# ASP.Net event calender for website with booking feature

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, fullcalendar, webforms

I need to design an event calender that will book different types of events. Let say an event will have

CreateEventCalender.aspx

```
Title: Some Title
Details: Details of the Event
Start Date: 10-June-2012
End Date: 20-June-2012
Start Time: 2PM
End Time:   4PM
Recurring: YES/NO
Block Date: YES/NO
ShowEventOnWebsite: YES/NO
EventVisible: YES/NO
Type Of Event: Activity / Event
```

Based on this our database will be similar to these entries along with the EventID.

I need to design a screen which will accept above details which will be managed by website admin only and other pages for public use..

1. Display Activity type event on Activity Page.
2. Display Event Type event on Event Page.
3. Display a Calender similar to one show in this link http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/
4. On Visitor Booking, Booking date should be block the days which are blocked by the admin and Dates like Saturday & Sunday should also be booked.

Just to mention CreateEventCalender.aspx is managed by website administer.

I would appreciate if someone can point me to an example that has similar functionality. I looked for it but could not find much. Few example are related to ASP.NET MVC while i need to do this for ASP.NET webform

I would also appreciate if someone can help me in converting the following example into asp.net webform
http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/2012/04/03/simple-event-calendar-asp-net.aspx

I am not sure if this used and payed control.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you mentioned is for the creation of an event calendar in asp.net webform. Could you specify the problems you have with integrating this control into your project?
Regarding day blocking, there is a client-side API for this purpose. Here is the related [doc](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxscheduler%3acollisions#work_hours_limiting)

Comment: I am struggling with the example & i cant add reference in ASP.Net webform as mentioned in point 1,2,3 of the example... & Point 4 i looked into my website folder it didnt create any new script file or any other file. have reference to system.web.mvc when i check under project property window..

Comment: In point 3 you should copy DHTMLX.dll from the folder bin of the Scheduler package to the folder App_Data of your project. Then add a reference to it. In point 4 copy the Scripts folder from the package to your project folder. Hope, it helps.

Comment: That was my indirect question. When i add reference to the website project in c# it does show the reference but doesnt add any .dll file in bin folder either. I am not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: I can try to create and MVC project first and then add reference to particular file and copy that dll from MVC project to my current website project App_Data folder may be that will work.. I am not sure

Comment: I have just checked it and had no problems with adding a reference. Try it again.

Comment: I even created a new web application project but nothing Happens i am doing some thing wrong can you please clear me the 2 point "Copy the library reference to your ‘App_Data’  project folder and go to References -> Add the reference to your application;

Comment: Try to open a sample from the package: schedulerPackage/Samples/Scheduler.ASP.NET

Comment: Can you give me the complete path

Comment: Here is the full path from the root of the trial package 
\Samples\Scheduler.ASP.NET\SchedulerNetAsp.csproj